# Requests get status code 401. What am i doing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, python-requests, basic-authentication

what am I doing wrong?
I get `401` code

I use sites API, here is an example from the site:

[image]

My code:

```py
import requests

login = "9163516566U1233"
password = "1233852"

get_url = "https://mrecord.mts.ru/api/v3/recs/9160551823/2019-07-24T00:00:00/2019-07-28T23:59:59"
b64_auth_str = "bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ="

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % b64_auth_str}

content_res = requests.get(get_url, headers=headers, auth=('login', 'password'))

print(content_res)
```

Output:

```
<Response [401]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `login` and `password` as string. Is that right? I guess it should be

```
content_res = requests.get(get_url, headers=headers, auth=(login, password))
```

At least you have set the variables.

Comment: anyway, everything remains as well